# Как проверить существование файла?

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система

Как проверить существование файла по определенному пути используя Python?

Comment: Взято отсюда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-if-a-file-exists-using-python

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
file_path = "path/to/file.txt"
```

Для проверки существования заданного пути используйте функцию `os.path.exists`:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(file_path)
```

Но она вернет `True` и для файла и для директории.

`os.path.isfile` проверит именно на наличие файла.

Answer (score 13):

**Кратко**: вместо `if exists(): open()` используйте просто `open()`.

---

Если проверка нужна, чтобы выполнить позднее какую-либо операцию с файлом, то лучше прямо выполнить эту операцию и поймать возможные ошибки (предполагая, что вы на том же уровне ошибки хотите обработать):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
try:
    file = open('input.txt')
except IOError as e:
    print(u'не удалось открыть файл')
else:
    with file:
        print(u'делаем что-то с файлом')
```

Предварительная проверка всё равно не гарантирует, что файл всё ещё будет существовать позднее и всё равно придётся ошибки обрабатывать.

В Питоне часто предпочтителен ["Проще просить прощения, чем разрешения" ( "It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission" -- `EAFP`) подход](http://habrahabr.ru/post/90493/) вместо ["Look before you leap." более распространённого в С](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

---

<sup>Ответы на комментарии:</sup>

> 1. Где блок finally в котором вы закрывается поток

`finally` здесь не нужен. Если код попал в `except` блок, то файл не открыт -- нечего закрывать. В `else` ветке, где файл открыт, `with file:` конструкция всегда закрывает файл при выходе из блока (нормальном или когда исключение возникло).

> 2. Конструкция try-exept-else многими считается плохо читаемой.

Обычно try/except не используется на том же уровне, то есть в коде используется просто:

```
with open('input.txt') as file:
    print(u'делаем что-то с файлом')
```

а *возможные исключения выше по стеку обрабатываются*. Но если вы хотите обработать ошибку в `open()` на том же уровне, то вы обязаны использовать try/except (`open()` сигнализирует ошибки с помощью исключений).

> 3. Каждый раз, когда файла нет, вы вызываете прерывание ОС (на нем строится механизм обработки исключения) самостоятельно, не слишком ли это раcточительно?

Исключения выбрасываются в случае ошибки в Питоне хотите вы этого или нет. Вот [реализация `os.path.exists()` из стандартной библиотеки](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/286e1c15ceb28a76d8ef4fe7111718317c9ccaf5/Lib/genericpath.py#L14-L22):

```
def exists(path):
    try:
        os.stat(path)
    except OSError:
        return False
    return True
```

фактически, используя `open()` напрямую, а не `if exists(): open()` мы *уменьшаем* количество системных вызовов.

> 4. Ваш код занял 7 строчек, не лучше ли эту задачу поручить операционной системе командой os.path.exists(path_to_file) в пару строчек ?

Длина кода, который не работает, не имеет значения. Ещё раз: вызов `os.path.exists()` не гарантирует что файл существует когда вы попытаетесь вызвать `open()` позднее: всё равно придётся обрабатывать ошибки.

Стоит упомянуть, что если отсутствие файла не является ошибкой в вашем случае (ожидается программой), то вполне можно `os.path.exists()` или его аналоги использовать, чтобы подчеркнуть вероятность отсутствия файла для читателя кода (но так как последующее открытие файла может быть всё равно неудачным, то это *не освобождает* код от добавления обработки ошибок, подходящего для вашей задачи, такого как try/except выше).

Comment: Ужасный пример. 1. Где блок `finally` в котором вы закрывается поток ? 2. Конструкция `try-exept-else` многими считается плохо читаемой. 3. Каждый раз, когда файла нет, вы вызываете прерывание ОС (на нем строится механизм обработки исключения) самостоятельно, не слишком ли это раcточительно ? 4. Ваш код занял 7 строчек, не лучше ли эту задачу поручить операционной системе командой `os.path.exists(path_to_file)` в пару строчек ?

Comment: @faoxis: у вас серьёзные пробелы в знании Питона 1- выучите, что `with file:` делает в Питоне 2- обычно try/except не используется на том же уровне, то есть в коде используется просто `with open('input.txt') as file:`, а возможные ошибки выше по стеку обрабатываются. 3- посмотрите на реализацию [`os.path.exists()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23cf14dad88fdd2527b9bd124956cff26564da2b/Lib/genericpath.py#L14-L22) 4- вызов `os.path.exists()` не гарантирует что файл существует когда вы попытаетесь  вызвать `open()` позднее: всё равно придётся обрабатывать ошибки.

Comment: я работаю `python junior`'ом. Чего же вы от меня ждете ? :)

Comment: @faoxis: тогда не делайте громкие заявления об ответе, если вы даже не понимаете код, который в нём написан. Объяснять, что ключевые слова (такие как `with`) в Питоне делают находится за рамками данного вопроса. Вы можете задать отдельный вопрос, если не ясно.

Comment: Я знаю, что такое with. Вы какой-то агрессивный программист. :)

Comment: @faoxis: ваш комментарий *"Где блок finally в котором вы закрывается поток ?"* однозначно указывает, что вы не понимает что `with file` делает. Учитывая многочисленные ошибки в комментариях, вы запутываете будущих читателей. Старайтесь оставлять более конструктивные комментарии и поменьше необоснованных суждений.

Answer (score 6):

```
import os

if os.path.exists(path_to_file):
   # файл существует
else:
   # файл не существует
```

Answer (score 4):

В версии Python 3.5, между директориями используется двойной обратный слэш

```
import os

if os.path.exists("Имя_папки\\Имя_папки\\anytext.txt"): 
     print ("Файл найден")
else: 
     print ("Файл не найден")
```

Вместо функции print, вы можете использовать любое другое действие - Всё на ваш вкус)

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
file_path = "path/to/file.txt"
if os.access(file_path, os.F_OK) == True:
            print("Файл существует")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    print('Txt-File has been opened!')
    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
except OSError:
    print('Txt-file created!')
    file = open('file.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]