# Нужно проверить наличие файла и выполнить с ним операцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно проверить наличие файла и поместить его в архив. Известен путь до файла. Неизвестно, существует этот путь или нет.

Мне нужно, чтобы выполнялось условие: если файл существует по указанному пути то архивировать; если нет, то пропустить.

Я мог бы и напрямую, но моя программа завершается на половине из-за ошибки нахождения файла. Мне нужно добавить в нее подобное условие.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Как проверить существование файла?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044)

Comment: Похожий, но не копия: в данном случае нужно также проверять, является ли путь директорией, как верно указал Timofey Bondarev в [данном комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444533/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e#comment469859_444563). Проголосовал за "оставить".

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы добавить файл в архив, если файл существует и пропустить его в противном случае:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(archive_path, 'a') as archive:
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            archive.write(filename)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass # ignore non-existing files
```

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю использовать функцию `os.path.isfile`, чтобы проверить правильность файла для архивации.

Функция `os.path.isfile` возвращает `true`, только если путь ведёт к файлу и этот файл существует.

```
import os
import gzip

def process_file(filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return
    with gzip.open(filename + '.gz', 'wb') as archive, open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        archive.write(f.read())

process_file('my/test/file.txt')
```

---

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) также предлагается использовать модуль `shutil` для копирования содержимого файлов:

```
import os
import shutil

def process_file(filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(filename + '.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Однако, для более надёжной работы с файлом рекомендуется использовать конструкцию `try except`, и конечный результат будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
import os
import shutil

def process_file(filename):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        return
    try: 
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f_in:
            with gzip.open(filename + '.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
    except IOError:
        pass  # обработка случая, когда файл только что был, но пропал
```

Comment: Но разве проверка на isfile() это python-way ? Насколько понимаю "нет". Надо обернуть вызов open внутри менеджера контекста и архивацию внутрь try-except блока

Comment: @sys_dev эта информация указана в конце ответа

Comment: В Вашем последнем варианте после слов "примерно так" следует код в котором все-таки есть 'if not os.path.isfile()'. Эту проверку вообще можно не делать! Оставив только и только try-блок

Comment: @sys_dev Я оставлял эту проверку для того, чтобы различать варианты файл/каталог от ошибок с чтением и отсутствием файла. Мне стоило это упомянуть, да. Вы правильно заметили, она действительно не обязательна.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, для проверки файл/каталог логичнее использовать os.path.isdir(filename)

Comment: 2 insolor: Посмотрите вариант от @jfs. Он более python-way и решает Вашу задачу! ;)

Comment: @sys_dev в варианте от jfs, если на вход пришла папка, то исключение не будет брошено, и создастся архив с **пустой** папкой.

Comment: @sys_dev, я уже ознакомился, еще в его ответе от 7 апреля (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044). В одной из моих задач требовалось в том числе и определять, передан ли на вход скрипту путь к директории (через isdir, тогда к нему добавлялось имя файла), и проверять, существует ли файл (проверяется через исключение, но не через isfile).

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, тесты показали, что если на вход дан путь к директории, без проверки isfile все-таки выбрасывается IOError (очевидно, директорию нельзя открыть с помощью open(filename, 'rb')). Но вообще, в случае архивации, директория - это по идее особый случай, который возможно потребуется обрабатывать особым образом - например упаковывать содержимое директории.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: архив создаётся в любом случае было исключение или нет. Я потестировал, верно, что если на вход `archive.write` дать папку, то пустая папка добавляется. Чтобы добавить файлы их необходимо явно указать. Чтобы исключить папки можно явный вызов `open(filename, 'rb')` добавить. В любом случае `isfile()` как в моём так и Вашем ответе бесполезен. В Вашем ответе `except IOError` слишко много ловит. Можно игнорировать только `FileNotFoundError` во время `open(filename, 'rb')` - другие ошибки следует пропускать наверх. Если Вы нашли ошибку в моём ответе, то оставьте к нему комментарий

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
import os
import gzip
...
if not os.path.isdir(dname):
    os.makedirs(dname)
else:
if os.path.exists(fname):
    in=open(fname,'rb')
    out=gzip.open(aname,'wb')
    out.write(in)
    out.close
    in.close
...
```