# Вынести путь папки в переменную в Python

Tags: python

В рабочем скрипте на Python очень много обращений к одним и тем же папкам с длинными путями.

Как правильно вынести путь в переменную?
Пример:

```
if os.path.exists("/opt/test1/test2/test3/file_ololo"):
    shutil.copyfile(r'/opt/test1/test2/test3/file_ololo',
        r'/opt/test1/test2/test3/managed/file_ololo_new')
```

Хочу ввести переменную `path_1 = /opt/test1/test2/test3/`

Comment: Сойдет, в принципе.

Comment: в сторону: вместо `if exists(): copy()` можно использовать: `try: copy() except FileNotFoundError:`. См. [Как проверить существование файла?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Часто имеет смысл вынести главную папку, относительно которой происходят действия, в отдельную переменную.

Остальные константы тоже стоит вынести в именованные переменные для удобства чтения.

В итоге код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
base_path = r'/opt/test1/test2/test3'
target_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'file_ololo')
copy_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'managed', 'file_ololo_new')

if os.path.exists(target_path):
    shutil.copyfile(target_path, copy_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
path = "/opt/test1/test2/test3"
if os.path.exists("{0}/file_ololo".format(path)):
      shutil.copyfile(r'{0}/file_ololo'.format(path), r'{0}/managed/file_ololo_new'.format(path))
```

Comment: А не подскажете, вот такую конструкцию можно переписать как-то так?

`path1 = '/tmp/folder1'
path2 = /tmp/folder2'
shutil.copyfile(r'{0}/file_ololo'.format(path), r'{0}/managed/file_ololo_new'.format(path1))


shutil.copyfile(r'{0}/file_ololo'.format(path), r'{1}/managed/file_ololo_new'.format(path ,path1))`
п.с. сори за кашу - в комментариях очень неудобно вставлять код(