# Писать условия или обрабатывать исключения?

Tags: python

Как вы считаете, лучше использовать условия в коде или обрабатывать исключения?

Пример использования условия:

```
import os

if os.path.exists("путь"):
    pass
```

Пример обработки исключений:

```
try:
    pass
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как проверить существование файла?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044)

Comment: Кстати (не отвечает на вопрос, но просто представляет некоторый интерес, учитывая выбранный пример), [посмотрите как `os.path.exists()` функция реализована](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4b8032df94a67351a5654d14698486c87d07888/Lib/genericpath.py#L14-L22).

Answer (score 4):

Ответ @Oma не вполне верен хотя бы потому, что выйдя за границы списка (в чистом Python нет массивов в их привычном понимании), будет возбуждено исключение IndexError. Если говорить о чистом Python, а не о модулях, то, по-моему, там всегда выбрасываются исключения, когда вы или ваша программа делаете что-то не так.

В официальной документации Python есть фраза 'Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission' - часто это действительно проще и читабельнее. Исключения будут полезны, если нужно застраховаться от чего-то действительно непредвиденного; если нужно прокидывать ошибку на несколько уровней логики вверх; если проверка каждый перед тем, как что-то сделать, слишком дорога.

Например, если вы открываете один раз в своей программе файл, гораздо проще будет завернуть открытие в `try/except`, чем проверять, существует ли он, есть ли права на его чтение/запись и т.п. Если вам на вход прилетает большое количество данных, и вам нужно их валидировать перед обработкой, и вы ожидаете что невалидных данных будет небольшой процент, весьма вероятно, что проверять их каждый раз будет слишком дорого. Поймать исключение подойдет лучше.

С другой стороны, если в последнем примере невалидных данных ожидается 50%, вероятно, что валидация окажется дешевле ловли исключений (это достаточно дорогая процедура).

Answer (score 2):

Использование `try/except` помимо плюсов, перечисленных @PavelGurkov также иключает возможности гонок между процессами, потому что при проверке на существование и до открытия/удаления/любой другой операции другой поток или программа могут открыть/удалить/переместить файл. Поэтому однозначно `try..except`

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос уже был.

> You should prefer `try/except` over `if/else` if that results in
>
> speed-ups (for example by preventing extra lookups)
>
> cleaner code (less lines/easier to read)
>   Often, these go hand-in-hand.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604636/better-to-try-something-and-catch-the-exception-or-test-if-its-possible-first

Answer (score 1):

Довольно развернутый ответ относительно того, что лучше выбрать: `try..except` или `if..else` и [влияет ли это на скорость](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2011-January/081143.html).

Вкратце: `try except` в "питоне" работает не так как в `c++` или `java` - он довольно быстр, однако, отлавливание исключений всё еще довольно дорогая операция и если логика в этом месте построена так, что возбуждение исключений возможно часто, и есть желание немного позаботиться о скорости, то вероятно есть смысл в угоду некоторой ясности воспользоваться `if..else`.
С другой стороны, как совершенно верно замечает автор:

> But mostly, don't worry about speed. If you are worried about 
>   *execution* speed, you shouldn't be using Python in the first place. 
>   Python is optimized for developer productivity, not execution speed. 
>   Write your code, and *if* it is too slow, then worry about finding the 
>   bottlenecks and optimizing them.

Comment: Откуда этот стереотип, что в c++ исключения какие-то медленные?

Comment: Никаких стереотипов, имеется ввиду, что в c++ if..else быстрее, чем try..catch.

Comment: Как Вы пришли к такому выводу?

Comment: Я краем уха слышал, что в c++ используются хитрые механизмы на стадии компиляции с запихиванием в бинарный файл специальных таблиц переходов и бог весть чего для последующей обработки в случае возникновения исключения. Совершенно не факт, что они медленные даже по сравнению с `if/else`.

Answer (score 0):

Не все твои возможные ошибки в коде идут в исключения, к примеру такие как выход за границы массива и т.д. Скорее тут необходимо комбинировать для большей безопасности. P.S. Хорошим кодом, считается код, где учтены всевозможные варианты развития событий.

Comment: Выход за границы массива таки выкидывает исключение