# Аналог basestring в Python3?

Tags: python, строки, python-3.x, типы

В Python2 строки обоих типов (`unicode` и `str`) были унаследованы от `basestring`. Это было очень удобно при проверке типов `isinstance(_, basestring)`. В Python3 соответствующие типы строк (`str` и `bytes`) полностью независимые и не имеют общего предка (в чем тут логика?). Из-за этого приходится писать конструкции типа `isinstance(_, (str, bytes))`, что довольно неэстетично.

С другой стороны, существуют встроенные типы-признаки, наподобие `collections.Iterable`, которые позволяют через `isinstance` проверять принадлежность значения некоторой категории типов. Например, `isinstance([], collections.Iterable)` возвращает `True`, несмотря на то, что `collections.Iterable` отсутствует среди предков списка `type([]).mro()`.

Вопрос: не существует ли подобного типа-признака для проверки всех типов строк, чтобы выполнялось условие `isinstance('', StringCategoty) and isinstance(b'', StringCategoty)` ?

**UPD:** Странно слышать, что `str` и `bytes` якобы не имеют между собой ничего общего, в то время как они реализуют почти идентичный программный интерфейс: из 44 (`str`) и 38 (`bytes`) их методов 36 - идентичны по своей функции и по форме вызова.

```
>>> str_methods = {method for method in dir(str) if not method.startswith('_')}
>>> bytes_methods = {method for method in dir(bytes) if not method.startswith('_')}
>>> shared_methods = str_methods.intersection(bytes_methods)
>>> len(str_methods)
44
>>> len(bytes_methods)
38
>>> len(shared_methods)
36
```

Вся суть различий двух типов строк сводится к тому, что один является закодированной/раскодированной формой другого. Даже их литералы записываются идентичным образом и отличаются только наличием префикса `b`. К тому же при работе с различными библиотеками ввода/вывода постоянно приходится иметь дело с обоими типами.

Comment: Вряд ли существует, потому что в третьем питоне это не нужно, ибо str и bytes не взаимозаменяемые

Comment: Проверка isinstance([], collections.Iterable) все правильно выдает вам, так как в данном случае происходит проверка на наличие методов свойственных итерируемому объекту, таких как `__next__` и `__iter__`.

Логика в том и есть, что в одном случае у вас строка для представления текстовой информации, а в другом случае последовательность байт.

Comment: Они не имеют достаточно общей функциональности чтобы иметь общий базовый класс.

Comment: @andreymal: @Avernial: Много ли общего между `dict` и `list` ? Только то, что оба они являются некими контейнерами. Для классификации их по этому признаку и существует `collections.Iterable`. А `str` и `bytes` по сути представляют собой примитив "строка" в закодированном и расодированном вариантах и имеют почти идентичный API (я добавил это в вопрос). Выявлять подобного рода примитивы на практике приходится чаще, чем искать неопределенного рода контейнеры. Да и принципы ООП требуют чтобы общий интерфейс выносился в виде абстрактного класса.

Comment: @cridnirk много ли общего между `str` и `bytes`? Только то, что оба они являются некими контейнерами. Один хранит символы, другой хранит байты. Один в доступе по индексу и в цикле выдаёт строки длиной в один символ, другой — числа (да-да, даже не `bytes`, а именно `int`). Один можно только закодировать, другой можно только раскодировать. Их нельзя складывать друг с другом. Похожесть только внешняя; технически они не имеют (почти) ничего общего и никаких всяких там абстрактных интерфейсов basestring иметь не должны.

Comment: Но для успокоения никто не мешает сделать `basestring = (str, bytes)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Кратко***: вместо `basestring`, в Python 3 используйте в зависимости от конкретного случая  `str` или `os.PathLike` или (`bytes, str)` или вообще вместо isinstance попробовать [EAFP подход](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044).

### Аргумент является текстом

Если вы работаете с текстом в Питоне, то используйте Unicode.

В Python 2, текст вперемешку мог быть представлен как байты  так и как Unicode (не удивительно, что интерфейс похожий).  Байты, представляющие текст, закодированный с помощью какой-либо кодировки, следует декодировать в Unicode перед дальнейшим использованием в программе, иначе легко получить [кракозябры (данные повреждены, а программа об этом не знает)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044).

В Питоне 3, используйте просто `isinstance(text, str)` там где в этом случае в Питоне 2 требовалось бы `isinstance(text, basestring)`.

### Аргумент является именем файла

Некоторые  данные могут быть почти всегда текстом, но формально допускать не текстовые значения. Например, часто имена файлов можно закодировать, используя `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` кодировку, но это не всегда возможно—на *nix имя файла может быть произвольной кашей байтов, не содержащей слэша `'/'` и ноль `'\0`'. Подробнее [Как работать с путями c русскими символами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044)

В этом случае, функции, работающие с путями могли принимать как Unicode, так и байты и поэтому использовать `basestring` в Питоне 2, в тех случаях когда isinstance оправдано. В Питоне 3, можно использовать [`os.PathLike`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.PathLike) если доступен, что позволяет принимать не только bytes, str, но и также `pathlib.Path`, `os.DirEntry`(`os.scandir()`) итд, чтобы представить имена файлов. Более вероятно, что [`os.fspath(path)` вызывается](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.fspath) в стиле EAFP, вместо `isinstance(path, os.PathLike)` (LBYL стиль). [Пример](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6463ec562047fcf5133b5ace2b524118621020c5/Lib/posixpath.py#L367-L376):

```
def abspath(path):
    """Return an absolute path."""
    path = os.fspath(path)
    if not isabs(path):
        if isinstance(path, bytes):
            cwd = os.getcwdb()
        else:
            cwd = os.getcwd()
        path = join(cwd, path)
    return normpath(path)
```

`abspath()` принимает любой `os.PathLike` объект. При этом использует OS API, которое только `str`, `bytes` понимает (`os.fspath()` гарантированно только `str`, `bytes` возвращает).

### `(str, bytes)`

На практике иногда приходится принимать как байты так и текст. К примеру, `subprocess.Popen` принимает аргументы командной строки как bytes и str (что OS API предоставляет). В Питоне не существует ABC, который бы представлял строки, получаемые от системы (аргументы командной строки, переменные окружения, пути), поэтому вместо `os.SystemString`, `Popen()` использует `(str, bytes)` когда нужна isinstance проверка.

Современный интерфейс принимал бы только строки здесь (str) и вызывал бы `os.fsencode()` в случаях, когда OS требует bytes. `sys.argv`, `os.environ` это коллекции str в Питоне (`surrogateescape` может быть использован). Относительно недавнее добавление в стандартную библиотеку `pathlib.Path` принимает только строки (str).

---

Из комментария внизу:

> ...применение isinstance для классификации значений целесообразно в случае, когда логика работы функции зависит от типа принятого аргумента. Примером может служить сама isinstance, которая (в статически типизированном ЯП) должна была бы принимать во втором аргументе только перечислимый тип, но (в Python) для простоты использования допускает передачу значения отдельного типа вместо кортежа/списка из одного элемента.

`Popen()` как раз является таким примером: она принимает команду (`args`) как строку или как список/коллекцию строк. Прямая цитата из [исходного кода](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6463ec562047fcf5133b5ace2b524118621020c5/Lib/subprocess.py#L1203-L1206):

```
        if isinstance(args, (str, bytes)):
            args = [args]
        else:
            args = list(args)
```

Другой пример, `fileinput.input()` функция, которая принимает либо файл либо список/коллекцию файлов. Из [её исходного кода](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6463ec562047fcf5133b5ace2b524118621020c5/Lib/fileinput.py#L190-L198):

```
    if isinstance(files, str):
        files = (files,)
    else:
        if files is None:
            files = sys.argv[1:]
        if not files:
            files = ('-',)
        else:
            files = tuple(files)
```

В данном случае, `fileinput` не обновлён на использование `os.PathLike`, а использует просто `str` (там где Python 2.7 использовал бы `basestring`)—клиенты кода вынуждены самостоятельно `os.fspath()` вызывать, когда необходимо.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Только я не рассматривал применение `isinstance` непосредственно перед использованием проверяемого значения (LBYL подход) - это излишне и неидиоматично с точки зрения Python. Речь шла о применении isinstance для классификации значений отдельно от их последующего использования в другом коде. Например, для вывода адекватных сообщений об ошибках  требуется валидация значений в точке, где они принимаются, когда внезапный выброс исключений из глубины библиотеки по причине невалидных данных, принятых в другой точке, не дает никакой информации для локализации проблемы.

Comment: Также применение `isinstance` для классификации значений целесообразно в случае, когда логика работы функции зависит от типа принятого аргумента. Примером может служить сама `isinstance`, которая (в статически типизированном ЯП) должна была бы принимать во втором аргументе только перечислимый тип, но (в Python) для простоты использования допускает  передачу значения отдельного типа вместо кортежа/списка из одного элемента.

Comment: @cridnirk EAFP это всего лишь один из вариантов, который следует упомянуть. Что я и сделал в двух предложениях, остальное—про isinstance. Это было бы заметным упущением в противном случае. Ответы на Stack Overflow не только лично для вас, а также для людей с похожим вопросом как он сформулирован.