# Почему в блоке исключения except FileNotFoundError функция повторно не запускается?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте!

Интересует повторный вызов функции `proverka_na_sohran()` из блока `except FileNotFoundError`, чтобы вернуть `result` значение переменной `С`.

Объясните, почему не работает, как я написал:

```
import json

def zapros_chisla():
    print("Ваше любимое число:")
    a = str(input())
    return a


def sohranenie_chisla():
    chislo = zapros_chisla()
    cats = "text\\cats.json"

    with open(cats, "w") as file:
        c = json.dump(chislo, file)


def proverka_na_sohran():
    cats = "text\\cats.json"

    try:
        with open(cats) as file:
            c = json.load(file)
            return c

    except FileNotFoundError:
        sohranenie_chisla()
        proverka_na_sohran()


result = proverka_na_sohran()


def vivod_chisla():
    print("Твоё любимое число - " + result)


vivod_chisla()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `result` вы сохраняете вызов проверки на сохранение. Но там оказывается `None`, потому что вы возвращаете туда ничего (**None**), ибо попадаете в блок `except`, где не стоит `return`, что означает `return None`.

**Почему так происходит?** Дело в том, что каждая функция в конце имеет неявное `return None`. Чтобы функция что-то возвращала, мы указываем в конце что мы хотим получить. Вы же разделяете свою функцию на две части `try` и `except`, и в одной вы указываете что возвращать, а в другой - нет, то есть оставляете неявное `return None`

Для примера можете посмотреть на следующую функцию:

```
def myreturn(a, b):
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)

    if a / b == 1:
        return True
    else:
        pass
        # return None неявно

print(myreturn(1, 1)) # True
print(myreturn(3, 2)) # None
```

Вы можете либо дописать что вы хотите вернуть, либо использовать цикл:

```
import json

def zapros_chisla():
    return input('Ваше любимое число: ')


def sohranenie_chisla():
    chislo = zapros_chisla()
    cats = r'text\cats.json'
    with open(cats, 'w') as file:
        c = json.dump(chislo, file)


def proverka_na_sohran():
    cats = r'text\cats.json'

    try:
        with open(cats) as file:
            c = json.load(file)
            return c

    except FileNotFoundError:
        sohranenie_chisla()


for i in range(2): # это вариант с циклом
    result = proverka_na_sohran()

def vivod_chisla():
    print("Твоё любимое число - " + str(result))

vivod_chisla()
```

Иными словами, функция `proverka_na_sohran()` вызывается, она возвращает значение в блок `except` но это значение никуда не сохраняется, оно просто возвращается вникуда. В этом проблема.

Чтобы не прибегать к циклу и при этом не возвращать `None` в блоке `except`, можно указать что мы хотим вернуть результат выполнения функции `proverka_na_sohran()`:

```
    except FileNotFoundError:
        sohranenie_chisla()
        return proverka_na_sohran() # возвращаем результат выполнения функции
```

Или же, если вам сложно понять как работает такая схема, можно сохранить результат, возвращенный вызовом функции, и вернуть его:

```
    except FileNotFoundError:
        sohranenie_chisla()
        temp_result = proverka_na_sohran() # в temp_result сохранили число
        return temp_result # вернули его
```

Comment: Задача была,чтоб при первом запуске программы,ф-ция vivod_chisla() выводила это число.Я думал, когда мы вызываем повторно ф-цию "proverka_na_sohran()",код в ней будет выполняться заново,следовательно блок "try" с загрузкой файла c = json.load(file) проходит проверку и возращает переменную "с" в "return"

Comment: @Александр код в ней заново и выполняется, но результат выполнения не возвращается в `result`. Вы просто возвращаете в блок `except` результат, а потом блок `except` возвращает `None`

Comment: @Александр сейчас обновлю ответ. Добавлю ещё вариант

Comment: @Александр обновил

Comment: Kit Scribe,Спасибо большое за ответ!!!Так действительно лучше.Я использовал хуже вариант,в блоке except FileNotFoundError добавил
        sohranenie_chisla()
        with open(cats) as file:
            c=json.load(file)
            return c

Comment: @Александр пожалуйста! Вопрос закрыт?

Comment: Kit Scribe,да благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Функция запускается, но её возвращаемое значение игнорируется в cлучае `FileNotFoundError` в вашем коде.

Минимально, не хватает `return` перед `proverka_na_sohran()` в `except` блоке, чтобы вернуть значение иначе `result is None` если файл не найден (когда `FileNotFoundError` выбрасывается).

Внутри функции её имя не является чем-то специальным. Рекурсивный вызов является таким же вызовом как и все остальные. Если вы хотите, чтобы `f()` функция вернула на каком-то шаге значение вызова `g()` функции, то следует `return` использовать:

```
def f(n):
    # ...
    return g(n-1)
```

Если убрать `return`, то это равнозначно просто отбрасыванию значения `g(n-1)` и приписыванию в конце `return None` (функция в Питоне *всегда* возвращает значение, даже если это значение является `None`):

```
def f(n):
    # ...
    g(n-1)  # XXX возвращаемое значение игнорируется
    return None  # это неявно присутствует
```

Совершенно аналогично в случае когда `g = f`:

```
def f(n):
    # ...
    return f(n-1) # возвращаем значение
```

и без `return` значение не возвращается:

```
def f(n):
    # ...
    f(n-1)  # XXX возвращаемое значение игнорируется
```

Наглядно, можно по шагам пройти на [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20f%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22the%20end%22%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%28n-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28f%283%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

---

Если вы хотите создать файл, если он ещё не существует, и только ваш код создаёт этот файл, то яснее возможно использовать LBYL подход вместо [EAFP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/23044):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from pathlib import Path

cats_file = Path(r"text\cats.json")
if not cats_file.exists():
    cats_file.write_text(json.dumps(dict(number=ask_int("Ваше любимое число:"))))
number = json.loads(cats_file.read_text())['number']
print(f"Твоё любимое число - {number}")
```

где [`ask_int()` может быть определён и с помощью `while True` цикла](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279).

Если вы хотите EAFP здесь, то можно явный цикл вместо рекурсивного вызова использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from pathlib import Path

cats_file = Path(r"text\cats.json")
for second in range(2):
    try:
        number = json.loads(cats_file.read_text())['number']
    except FileNotFoundError:
        if not second:  # the first attempt
            number = ask_int("Ваше любимое число:")
            cats_file.write_text(json.dumps(dict(number=number)))
        else:
            raise  # allow to propagate
    else:
         break  # success

print(f"Твоё любимое число - {number}")
```

В этом случае, если файл не существует, то у пользователя запрашиваются данные и создаётся файл. При второй попытке, если файл снова не существует, то ошибке позволено всплыть выше по стеку.