# Как проверить наличие файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я попробовал два способа:

1.

```
    f = path(file_location + '1_classes/' + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt')
    if f.is_file():
        self.uch()
        file.close()
    else:
        self.och()
        file.close()
```

2.

```
        try:
    file = open(file_location + "1_classes/" + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt')
    except IOError as e:
        self.och()
        file.close()
    else:
        self.uch()
        file.close()
```

Oба способа не работают. Если нужно, я находил путь к файле так:

```
file_location + '1_classes/' + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'
```

Путь формируется правильно, проверено.
Даже при наличии файла, код открывает окно, которое сообщает об ошибке.

Comment: `try: ... except FileNotFoundError: ...`.

Comment: вы наверное не поняли. Даже при наличии файла, код открывает окно , которое сообщает об ошибке.

Comment: О какой ошибке?

Comment: Я открываю, заранее созданное окно, сообщающее об ошибке.

Comment: Может, Вам подойдёт `os.path.exists`?

Comment: Тут достаточно много решений:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414593/Как-проверить-существование-файла

Comment: Я извиняюсь, в коде была ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `os.path.exists(*file_path*)` из либы `os`
Данный метод возвращается `true` при существовании файла. В `file_path` указывайте конечный адрес файла.

```
if os.path.exists(file_location + '1_classes/' + self.lineEdit1.text() + '.txt'):
    self.uch()
    file.close()
else:
    self.och()
    file.close()
```