# Как на python3 узнать подключен ли дисковод?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, железо

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на python из под ubuntu 20.04.1 узнать установлен ли cdrom?
Необходимо написать скрипт, который открывает cdrom и копирует данные во временную папку. Но прежде чем открывать дисковод, нужно проверить присутствует ли этот дисковод в системе.

Answer (score 1):

CDROM в Линукс подключается через драйвер sr (можно поискать в /sys/) и создает устройство `/dev/sr0`.

Comment: Понял. спасибо. А не подскажите как в коде обратиться к системным данным?

Comment: К каким именно и как обратиться?

Comment: К системным данным, иллюстрирующим наличие или отсутствие устройства с именем sr0. Под обращением имеется в виду получение информации указывающей на отсутствие дисковода.

Comment: @Enreward_Ronkhall https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414593/178576