# Как вывести содержимое каталога в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, python-import

Я пока только постигаю python, прошу помочь. Суть проблемы: надо написать программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя путь к каталогу и выводит в консоль его содержимое в виде списка файлов и каталогов. Для каждого элемента списка программа должна выводить имя, тип (файл или каталог), дату создания и размер (в кибибайтах, только для файлов). Список должен быть отсортирован по имени по возрастанию
Результат работы приложения должен выводиться в консоль в следующем виде:

```
Имя файла      Тип        Дата создания    Размер (КиБ)
---------      ---        -------------    ------------
.idea          Каталог    2015.12.31       -
main.py        Файл       2015.12.31       15
```

Мой код:

```
import os
print("Имя файла     Тип     Дата создания     Размер (КиБ)")
print("---------     ---     -------------     ------------")
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
print(os.path.getctime(__file__))
print(os.path.getsize(__file__))
```

Что выводит у меня:

```
    Имя файла      Тип        Дата создания    Размер (КиБ)
    ---------      ---        -------------    ------------
    main.py
    1625142504.6292036
    271
```

То есть я не знаю как написать функцию для типа (файл или каталог), для даты у меня проблемы (неправильно выводится), а размер выводится скорее всего в байтах, я попробовал перевести в кибибайты умножив на *0.00097656, но размер стал 282, что неверно. Как сделать так, что было как в примере? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Проверить, является ли пуль файлом можно через `os.path.isfile("<path>")`

[Так же есть другие варианты решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414593/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)

На счет размера файла - почему бы не делить на 1024 ? Будет читабельнее, и будете уверены что точно правильно.

Дата создания файла - `os.stat()` для линукса, `os.path.getctime()` для винды, [источник](https://askdev.ru/q/kak-poluchit-datu-vremya-sozdaniya-i-izmeneniya-fayla-v-python-1116/)

Так же проверьте работу на только что созданном файле

---

UPD: С чего решили что размер неверный? Какой должен быть? на сколько разница?

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getctime()` возвращает количество секунд, прошедшее с 1 января 1970 года, 00:00:00 (UTC). Поэтому прежде чем печатать дату, нужно это число конвертировать в нужный формат, например так:

```
d = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d", os.path.getctime(__file__))
```

Выводить не тремя разными принтами, а в одном, чтобы все осталось в одной строчке:

```
name = os.path.basename(__file__)
date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", os.path.getctime(__file__))
size = os.path.getsize(__file__)
print(name, date, size)
```

Ну и добавить между переменными табуляторов (`"\t"`), по потребности или выровнять через форматирование строк.